# arabxetex: how to properly write wasla sign?

Tags: arabic, arabtex, arabxetex

How can I create ["wasla"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasla_(diacritic)) signs using `arabxetex`? Writing `qad-i in.sarafa` (an example from the `arabtex` documentation) produces:

[image]

In `arabtex`, it produces:

[image]

How can I get the same effect in `arabxetex`?

Comment: Try with   `qad  i-n.sarafa`  with   `full voc`  option

Answer (score 1):

This is less an answer than a comment that’s too long for a comment.

Page 7 of the `arabxetex` manual includes verses from the Quran containing instances of waṣla:

```
\begin{arab}[fullvoc]
sUraTu 'l-ssajdaTi

bi-'AyAtinA 'lla_dIna

`ani 'l-ma.dAji`i

tu_tIru 'l-'ar.da

tasq.I 'l-.har_ta

bi-'l-.haqqi
\end{arab}
```

These examples don’t look quite like what I’d expect from the documentation of `arabtex`; and all but one of the examples of waṣla in the `arabtex` documentation produce bad results in `arabxetex`.

The example that works is `wa-ismuhu`.  I can fix some of the other examples:

```
\begin{arab}[fullvoc]
f--a-n.sarafa% not f--a-in.sarafa

'al-i-smu% not 'al-i-ismu

qad i-n.sarafa% not qad-i in.sarafa, as salim bou pointed out

yA i-bnI% not yA ibnI

h_a_dA i-bnuh_u% not h_a_dA ibnuh_u

'al-i-^stirA'u% not 'al-i-i^stirA'u
\end{arab}
```

No luck yet with the remaining examples.

The documentation for `arabxetex` should address this, because it’s not just obvious how one is supposed to adapt the ASCII transliteration of `arabtex` for `arabxetex`.

Comment: You're a wizard! Should I send the `arabxetex` maintainer a note with a link to our discussion?

Comment: @user89 That may be a good idea.  I worked this out at 3 o’clock in the morning, which may be why I couldn’t fix all the examples, but (still sleepy? and not really a wizard) I’ve had no more light on them.  It would be nice if we could send the maintainer a complete account to insert into the documentation, but perhaps these cases will be enough to help someone else work out what’s going on.

Answer (score 0):

See the output below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}

\setcode{utf8}
\<قَدِ ٱنْصَرَفَ.  >

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, but this uses `arabtex`, and not `arabxetex`. Also, it uses arabic input, rather than `arabtex`-like input.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to stick with `arabxetex`?

Comment: I thought it was more modern and up-to-date compared to `arabtex`? At least, that is the impression I got from its manual?